# Unable to open C# script files in Unity, MacOS

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine, scripting, editor

Any new or old **Script files** in *Unity* are unable to open. *Mac OS* suggests to search for the application in App Store or, from applications. Although, I couldn't find any solution or, suggestions to use any **External Script Editor**, or simply go back to default editor.

Unity version: (2018.4.14f1 personal)

Mac OS Catalina 10.15.1

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've found a solution for now, it was *updating unity to the new version*, basically I added **Visual Studio** for mac option while downloading an update.

But, loading scripts on visual studio, Visual studio must be opened but previously I used to just open the scripts and read/write on it. Any mac users, any help simpler than this would help me a-lot.